# Visio internal error: #3400 Action 2463: ??? When Saving to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-visio

I was wondering if anyone has ran into this error message before as it brings up completely nothing on the web in regards to saving Visio files.
The user is trying to save a Visio document direct to her OneDrive folder in file Explorer and gets this internal error which evidently doesn't even know itself, why it is popping up?

It can happen to an existing document within the folder or a brand new one saving there for the first time.

Can anyone tell me why this error appears or if they have stumbled upon a description of the error code? Because I cant seem to find a reason for it anywhere.

The only work around I have found for this issue is saving the file to the users desktop and cutting it back into the OneDrive folder, Thus Overwriting the old copy and this is rather messy...

Answer (score 0):

This post may be months old but this might help. If there are any special characters within the file name when saving it to One Drive, try taking them out. May it be a comma, dot or an ampersand `&`. Then save the file directly to One Drive.

Comment: Seriously? *Dot (**```.```**)* is a special character than can cause problems?